# ionic build generate android app with old support library

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I am building ionic app, when I run `ionic cordova add android` the android app is created successfully but when open it to build in using android studio I got errors in some activities that `android.support.v4` not found and it is solved when changing it to `androidx`, where should I change this settings from ionic application itself to avoid build issues in android studio ?

Comment: Usually, these happen for version mismatching of plugins you are using, you should see which plugin version is mismatching while `npm install`. Find out the odd plugin and update it to the latest version, this should do the trick

Comment: @SoumikBhattacharjee it is an open source project that I am trying to build and I am not aware of all plugins, is there any command that can tell me which plugin is mismatched ?

Comment: Have you tried the `npm install` command? It should give you hint about the mismatched plugin

Comment: Please show the expected/desired results, the actual results (which includes any error messages), and explain how the latter fails to meet the former. Consult the [help] articles for more guidelines, especially "[ask]" and providing a [mcve]. See also "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/90527)".

Answer (score 0):

as explained in [docs](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/android/troubleshooting#error-package-androidsupport-does-not-exist), you need to wait for the plugin developers to fix it and in the meantime a workaround is to patch the plugin with jetifier:

```
npm install jetifier
npx jetify
npx cap sync android
```

If you want to change the plugin, you have a create a new custom plugin and copy their code into it and change it there, which is usually harder.